# Именованные блоки в Swift

Tags: swift, lambda, blocks

Как использовать в Swift именованные блоки? По типу как в c++ именованную лямбду:

`auto fnobj = []() { return 5; };
 auto x = 5*fnobj();`

У меня получалось только блоки возвращающие `Void` именовать - для GCD `dispatch_block_t` типа. Но как использовать блоки возвращающие нечто другое, например `Int`, и использовать их в выражениях - как в примере выше?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let sumBlock: (Int, Int) -> Int = { (a: Int, b: Int) in return a + b }
let sum = sumBlock(1, 2)
```

Comment: Спасибо! Я уже к этому времени разобрался, но с автоопределением типа: ```let sumBlock = { (a: Int, b: Int) -> Int in return a + b }```

Comment: Я специально написал тип, чтобы вы увидели как его задать:)